# скрипт, находящий в заданном каталоге и всех его подкаталогах все файлы с параметрами

Tags: linux, bash

скрипт, находящий в заданном каталоге и всех его подкаталогах все файлы, владельцем которых является заданный пользователь. Имя владельца и каталог задаются пользователем в качестве первого и второго аргумента командной строки. Скрипт выводит результаты в файл (третий аргумент командной строки) в виде полный путь, имя файла, его размер. На консоль выводится общее число просмотренных файлов.

```
#!/bin/bash
# 1 user 
# 2 dir find
# 3 export file
find $2 -user $1 -type f | du -ah > $3
find $2 -type f | wc -l
```

как вывести в нужном формате? полный путь, имя файла, его размер

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash
# 1 user 
# 2 dir find
# 3 export file
# find "$2" -user "$1" -type f -exec readlink -f {} \; | xargs du -ah | awk '{ print $2" "$1 }' > "$3"
find "$2" -user "$1" -type f -exec readlink -f {} \; | xargs ls -l | awk '{ print $9"\t"$5 }' > "$3"
find "$2" -type f | wc -l
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash
# 1 user 
# 2 dir find
# 3 export file
find "$2" -user "$1" -type f -fprintf "$3" '%h\t%f\t%s\n' 
wc -l < "$3"
find "$2" -type f | wc -l
```

Comment: Полный путь не нужен?